# Does SafeArrayAccessData ever return a pointer different from pvData?

Tags: c++, safearray

I know that SafeArrayAccessData also does locking/unlocking, but never mind that, I'm interested only to know if it ever returns a pointer different from `pvData`.

For example, this code never triggers the assert (that I could see in my tests):

```
SafeArrayAccessData(sa, (void**) &ptr);
assert(ptr == sa->pvData);
```

Does anyone know of a scenario where `SafeArrayAccessData` would yield a pointer that is not equal to `pvData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way the out-parameter pointer set by `SafeArrayAccessData()` would be other than `psa->pvData` would be if the function's return value is other than `S_OK` (e.g. the array could not be locked, in which case the out-parameter's value is unspecified).

If the function does return `S_OK`, the out-parameter pointer must equal `psa->pvData` (after all, what else could it be?).

Comment: I was asking because there is already SafeArrayLock/SafeArrayUnlock, which makes SafeArrayAccessData/SafeArrayUnaccessData kind of redundant, so I thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: I see.  Well, note the docs for the Lock function: "*Increments the lock count of an array, and places a pointer to the array data in pvData of the array descriptor.*"  So if you fail to lock at all, `pvData` might not be valid, I suppose.  But in the use case you have, I don't think it matters which function you use--it's just a matter of convenience/style.